# Issue after installation of Windows 10 update

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

Two days ago, Windows 10 updated successfully and after update, it was working fine.

Today morning, when I turn on, it says, *Automatic Repair*.

After few minutes, *Automatic Repair* failed, then I saw other options; *Shut Down*, *Restart* and *Advanced Option*.

Using *Advanced Option*, I tried to restore but unable to restore at any restore point.

Then, I tried to *Reset this PC with Keep My Files*, its failed.

Now I have only one option i.e. *Reset this PC with Remove everything*.

I tried, *Uninstall Updates* (under *Advanced Options*). It’s failed.

Now I selected *Reset this PC with Remove everything*. It's also failed.

There is no another computer and USB stick so that bootable stick can be created for Clean Installation can be done.

Pls let me know, what is another way?

Using *Advanced Option*, *Command Prompt* can be accessed.

Is there anyway so that it can be resolved through *Command Prompt*?

Pls help me for resolving the issue.

With Regards

TekQ

Comment: Where I see this happens (a few times at different clients) the issue is the drive (hard drives in our cases). Get the manufacturer's hardware test application on a bootable USB key and test the hardware. Most likely the drive.

Comment: I am confused on what you are asking. Are you asking for a way to do a fresh install without having access to the Media Creation tool? i.e. you don't have another computer you can download Windows 10 on and create a bootable media?

Comment: Try in the Command Prompt to enter the command `bcdedit /set {current} recoveryenabled No` and reboot. Or maybe `bcdedit /set {default} recoveryenabled No`. If this fails, do you have a Windows installation media in either an ISO file or a DVD?

Comment: @Ziggy32 As I said, no USB and no another computer so that bootable USB can be created for clean installation. Only Command Prompt (through Advanced Option), can accessed.

Comment: I think you need to find a friend who can help you make a USB Key to test hardware and also to reinstall Windows if that is practical

Comment: Please specify which update you installed

Comment: This is almost certainly a failing disk drive. It needs to be properly tested as already mentioned. But, in a last ditch effort you could try running `chkdsk /r` at the command prompt. Make sure you have the actual windows partition active. It will probably not be the C: drive in your recovery mode, but maybe. That is what `diskpart` can help you figure out.

Comment: I came to know, two similar cases. Windows update installed successfully, after installation it was working fine, Automatic Repair appears next day, couldn’t be restore at any point and Reset this PC with both options failed. It’s really disappointing and frustrating. Unfortunately, in both cases, only C: drive is there with all data.